# Can't iterate through a string and collect a list of strings in python. Typerror?

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror

I'm looking to be able to gather a list of strings which divides a larger string by the marker ',

However, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Here's my code if somebody could take a look at it

```
for f in phonebook:
    print f
    if phonebook[f] + phonebook[f+1] == "'," :
        lineString = phonebook[startpoint:(f+1)]
        arrayOfStrings[j] = lineString
        startpoint = f+2
        j = j+1 #iterate through the array 

return arrayOfStrings
```

A sample of how I want the code in the end would be like:

print arrayOfStrings[1]

+445557284

print arrayOfStrings[4]

+445558928
etc.

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: It's a good idea to provide an example list and show what kind of output you want from it. Aesthete is a pretty basic example on what's wrong with this code but it doesn't seem to really do what you want in the end.

Comment: This whole block of code *looks* equivalent to `arrayOfStrings = [x.strip("'") for x in phonebook.split(",")]`, although it's hard to be sure without seeing the data.

Answer (score 3):

Every `f` is going to be one of the strings in the list `phonebook`. It's a list, so it needs to be indexed by integers, as you can see.

What you want is `enumerate`

```
for idx, val in enumerate(phonebook):
  if phonebook[idx] + phonebook[idx+1] == "',"
```

You should also make sure to check your bounds, otherwise you're going to run over the end of the list here!

There is also a recipe for `pairwise` that you could implment:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
  "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
  a, b = tee(iterable)
  next(b, None)
  return izip(a, b)

for a, b in pairwise(phonebook):
  if a + b == "',":
```

Comment: Can also be written as `val + phonebook[idx + 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`f` is not an index into `phonebook`, it is a *value **from** `phonebook`*. If you need an index into it, use `enumerate` to add that index to your loop. Because you are looking at the *next* item in `phonebook` as well, only loop over all but the last value:

```
for i, char in enumerate(phonebook[:-1]):
    if char + phonebook[i + 1] == "',":
        lineString = phonebook[startpoint:i + 1]
        arrayOfStrings[j] = lineString
        startpoint = i + 2
        j += 1
```

In this case, you can even have `enumerate` start at 1 for an easy offset:

```
for next_index, char in enumerate(phonebook[:-1], 1):
    if char + phonebook[next_index] == "',":
        lineString = phonebook[startpoint:next_index]
        arrayOfStrings[j] = lineString
        startpoint = next_index + 1
        j += 1
```